# How to optimize this short Spark Apache DataFrame function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Following function is supposed to join two DataFrames and return the number of checkouts per location. It is based on the Seattle Public Library [data set](https://www.kaggle.com/seattle-public-library/seattle-library-checkout-records/version/1#Checkouts_By_Title_Data_Lens_2005.csv).

```java
  def topKCheckoutLocations(checkoutDF: DataFrame, libraryInventoryDF: DataFrame, k: Int): DataFrame = {
    checkoutDF
      .join(libraryInventoryDF, "ItemType")
      .groupBy("ItemBarCode", "ItemLocation") //grouping by ItemBarCode and ItemLocation
      .agg(count("ItemBarCode")) //counting number of ItemBarCode for each ItemLocation
      .withColumnRenamed("count(ItemBarCode)", "NumCheckoutItemsAtLocation")
      .select($"ItemLocation", $"NumCheckoutItemsAtLocation")
    }
```

When I run this, it takes ages to finish (40+ minutes), and I'm pretty sure it is not supposed to take more than a couple of minutes. Can I change the order of the calls to decrease computation time?

As I never managed to finish computation I never actually got to check whether the output is correct. I assume it is.

The checkoutDF has 3 mio. rows.

Comment: Time taken to execute depends on the dataset size and Executor memory, number of Executors and Cores of the machine on which you are executing. Please specify those configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spark job performance

- Select the required column from the dataset before joins to
  decrease data size
- Partition your both dataset by join column ("ItemType") to avoid shuffling